# Google BigQuery SQL: Calculate users that come from other shops

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to count unique users by shops, where the first visit was in another shop.
I have two tables:
Visits

```
ShopID  UserID
10      1001
11      1002
12      1001
13      1002
14      1001
15      1003
16      1005
17      1002
18      1003
10      1005
11      1003
12      1002
13      1005
```

and
First_Visit:

```
UserID  First ShopID
1001       10
1002       13
1003       18
1005       16
```

Need Output as

```
ShopID  Total Users from other shops
10               0
11               2
12               2
13               1
14               1
15               1
16               0
17               1
18               0
```

I can calculate for a single ShopID , but can not calculate dynamically for each ShopID:

```
SELECT 
shopid,
COUNT (DISTINCT UserID) AS TOTAL_USERS
FROM project.dataset.table_visits
WHERE shopid=12
AND UserID IN
(
    SELECT UserID
    FROM project.dataset.table_first_visit
    WHERE shopid<>12
)
GROUP BY shopid
```

How can this be done dynamically for each ShopID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with visits as (
  select 10 as shopid, 1001 as userid union all
  select 11, 1002 union all
  select 12, 1001 union all
  select 13, 1002 union all
  select 14, 1001 union all
  select 15, 1003 union all
  select 16, 1005 union all
  select 17, 1002 union all
  select 18, 1003 union all
  select 10, 1005 union all
  select 11, 1003 union all
  select 12, 1002 union all
  select 13, 1005)
, first_visit as (
  select 1001 as userid, 10 as first_shopid union all
  select 1002, 13 union all
  select 1003, 18 union all
  select 1005, 16
)
select
  shopid,
  count(distinct if(shopid != first_shopid, userid, null)) as users_from_other_shop
from visits join first_visit using(userid)
group by shopid
order by shopid
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking you want a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select v.shop_id,
       count(*) as total_visits,
       count(distinct v.userId) as total_users,
       count(distinct case when fv.userId is null then v.userId end) as total_users_from_other_shops
from `project.dataset.table_visits` v left join
     `project.dataset.table_first_visit` fv
     on fv.userId = v.userId
group by v.shop_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below join-less solution (which I expect to be more effective in terms of execution duration and orders more effective in terms of slot consumption)

```
select shopid, sum(flag) users_from_other_shop
from (
  select distinct shopid, userid, 1 flag
  from `project.dataset.table_visits` 
  union all 
  select distinct first_shopid, userid, -1 
  from `project.dataset.table_first_visit` 
)
group by shopid
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]